# How can I find a png image's boundary of using objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, image, image-processing

Here is the UIImage, Wikipedia icon, 
[image]

But it is a png file, but I would like to find the boundary of this image like this(Sorry, ugly drawing):

[image]

Is there any existing algorithm that allow me to find out the image? 
Here is the assumption: 
1. All the background is transparent. 
2. The image MUST be one big piece.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for [this](https://github.com/Nyx0uf/NYXImagesKit). I didn't tried this myself but it will solve your problem seems. Here's the [tutorial](http://cocoaintheshell.com/2012/01/nyximagesutilities-nyximageskit/).

```
UIImage* edge = [myImage edgeDetectionWithBias:0];
```

I am not sure, if it will solve your problem.